# Can I just drop vjslib.dll into the /bin directory of my application?

Tags: iis, deployment, j#

I am in the middle of a production deployment.  Unfortunately I am deploying to a tightly controlled environment.  It is unlikely I'm going to get clearance tonight to run the full Visual J# redistributable EXE.  Our app is currently throwing errors saying that it can't find the assembly "vjslib.dll".  Can I just drop this into the bin of our app and have everything work without all the hassle of the full-blown EXE install for the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **vjslib.dll** file is a redistributable file.  You should be able to place it in the BIN directory and have everything work just fine unless there is another dependency missing.  You may need to add **vjsnativ.dll** as well.

Comment: I did need vjsnativ.dll and vjscor.dll; otherwise it worked.  I got my hand slapped because the engineer dropped them in the middle of the day, BUT IT WORKED!!

Comment: Works, only xcopy development  vjslib, vjsnativ, vjscor assemblies  without forcing him to install the J# redistributable ? Works in .NET 4.0 ?