# Distribute .NET Application that uses J# without J# framework

Tags: asp.net, j#

I have an ASP.NET website that uses one of J# redistributable library. Is there a way to deliver this website to the client (which has .NET framework installed, but not J# Framework) without forcing him to install the J# redistributable ?

Answer (score 0):

No. The code that uses J# needs that library installed.

Comment: I only use xcopy deployment: vjslib, vjsnativ, vjscor assemblies ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1061554/can-i-just-drop-vjslib-dll-into-the-bin-directory-of-my-application